# Shared hosting banwidth limits

Tags: bandwidth, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting account with a 20GB monthly bandwidth limit. I have exceeded my monthly limit and according to my host my counter is never reset, they say they use a continuous 30 day counter.

So for example, I make payment on the 1st of each month, say I use 20GB in the last week of the month. My bandwidth counter is not reset on the 1st of the new month and my bandwidth will only become available in the last week of the new month.

Is this common practice by shared hosting companies?

Sounds a bit shady to me. Surely my counters should be reset on the 1st of every month when I make payment and 20GB of bandwidth should be available from the day payment is made?

Answer (score 1):

That's not fair, move providers and let them know why.

Comment: Agreed.  Give them a piece of their mind; deceptive business practices will not be tolerated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking for a new hosting company.

If you're paying for a package at X a month which included Ygb of data transfer you should be getting what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Many providers usually allow you to purchase additional bandwidth with extra cost for over usage.

Answer (score 0):

> Sounds a bit shady to me. Surely my
>   counters should be reset on the 1st of
>   every month when I make payment and
>   20GB of bandwidth should be available
>   from the day payment is made?

Nothing shady here. Running reset, basically. As long as it is properly documented and you can see it before you sign... the "shady" part is more a "stupid consumer" than anything else. So, the question for you is - did you just not do your homework or did the provider hide that from you?

That said, it is quite common, quite a lot of hosting panels do that. has the advantage that people dont get their budget "on one big run". I know of two panels implementing it like this.

Pracitally it makes no difference. Really. Banwidth is not that expensive and if you run a non-joke site the basic question is... nonexistent. You pay what you need because the site being down for whatever time is simply not acceptable. If I imagine some of my servers being down shutting my busienss down for even 3 days... impossible to believe.